# array's value is getting reset while flipping boolean value in useState react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, boolean

here I'm trying to insert a value in an array called **itemList** when the user clicks on the **button**. and after inserting the value, I want to **flip** the value of **isCross**. But, it reset the array at its initial value.
and when I comment **setIsCross(!isCross)**

So why is this happening?
*App.js*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { FaRegCircle, FaTimes } from "react-icons/fa";
import { BsDash } from "react-icons/bs";
import "./App.css";

import Icon from "./components/Icon";

const App = () => {
  // States declared
  const [isCross, setIsCross] = useState(true);

  // list created
  const itemList = new Array(9).fill("empty");

  // function on click
  const btnClicked = (index) => {
    if (itemList[index] === "empty") {
      itemList[index] = isCross ? "cross" : "circle";
      setIsCross(!isCross);

      console.log("Items: ", itemList);
    } else if (itemList[index] !== "empty") {
      alert("already filled...");
    }
  };

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   console.log("useEffect: ", itemList);
  // }, [isCross]);
  return (
    <div className="space-between">
      <div className="header flex">
        <div className="section">
          <FaRegCircle className="icon" />
          <span></span>
          <BsDash className="dash" />
        </div>
        <span className="divider-line"></span>
        <div className="section">
          <FaTimes className="icon" />
          <span></span>
          <BsDash className="dash" />
        </div>
        {itemList}
      </div>
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-area">
          <div className="row-span">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </div>
          <div className="col-span">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="game-box">
          {itemList.map((item, index) => (
            <div
              onClick={() => btnClicked(index)}
              key={index}
              className="icon flex"
            >
              <Icon name={item} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="footer flex">
        <span>
          Created️ by{" "}
          <a
            href="https://anilrkhairnar.github.io/"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
            target="_blank"
          >
            Anil Khairnar
          </a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Icons are coming from this file

*Icon.js*

```
import React from "react";
import { FaRegCircle, FaTimes } from "react-icons/fa";
import { BsDash } from "react-icons/bs";

const Icon = ({ name }) => {
  switch (name) {
    case "circle":
      return <FaRegCircle className="icon" />;
    case "cross":
      return <FaTimes className="icon" />;
    default:
      return <div></div>;
  }
};

export default Icon;
```

Comment: `itemList` isn't state so whenever the component is re-rendered it gets initialised again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't really understand your own code. When you call set state i think your application re-renders, if you want to hold the state of the itemList then you should use useState. if you want the array to remember the value of its index then you should tell react how to store and remember its value.

Answer (score 0):

When a `setState()` function is called, as long as it is not explicitly excluded as dependency of your componenent's `useEffect()`, it will cause a re-render of your component ([read more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)).

This re-render is what causes your array to reset. In order to prevent this, you could make your list a state too, like so:

```
  // list created
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState(new Array(9).fill("empty"));

  // function on click
  const btnClicked = (index) => {
    if (itemList[index] === "empty") {
      const newItemList = itemList.slice(); // make copy of itemList

      // update item at index and set state
      newItemList[index] = isCross ? "cross" : "circle";
      setItemList(newItemList);
      setIsCross(!isCross);

      console.log("Items: ", itemList);
    } else if (itemList[index] !== "empty") {
      alert("already filled...");
    }
  };
```